# Using nightwatch-html-reporter, is there a way to append a timestamp to the reportFilename?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Am new to Nightwatch and Javascript in general, and am successfully using [nightwatch-html-reporter](https://github.com/jls/nightwatch-html-reporter), except every test overwrites the previously generated html report.  I tried adding a timestamp to the reportFilename in my globals.js file and get an error after my test execution similar to:

Error generating report: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Automation\nightwatch\reports\generatedTestResults_2016-04-15_23:14:30.736_.html'

This is my entire globals.js file:

```
var d = (new Date).toISOString().replace(/z|t/gi,'_').trim();
var HtmlReporter = require('nightwatch-html-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
  openBrowser: false,
  reportsDirectory: "/reports",
  reportFilename: "generatedTestResults_"+d+".html",
  themeName: "default"
});

module.exports = {
  reporter: reporter.fn
}
```

The goal is to have a different generated report saved for each test.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error you are seeing is because the filename you are generating includes ':' characters.  If you used something like

```
var d = Date.now();
```

Then the filename would be ok.  You could also update to the latest version of nightwatch-html-reporter (1.0.5) and it includes an option to append a timestamp to the end of the filename.

Then your reporter options would look like:

```
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
  openBrowser: false,
  reportsDirectory: "/reports",
  uniqueFilename: true,
  reportFilename: "generatedTestResults.html",
  themeName: "default"
});
```